What does it mean when the transition function of a NFA returns an empty set?
Given a NFA, $N = (Q, \Sigma, q_0, \partial, F_Q)$, where $\partial$ is the transition function $Q \times (\Sigma \cup \{ \varepsilon \} ) \to \mathcal{P}(Q) $. So $\partial(q, a)$ returns a set, which can be any element of $\mathcal{P}(Q)$.
Sounds great, but I don't know how to interpret what's going on when the return value of the transition function is an empty set $\emptyset$. Say the machine is at the state $q$, and I apply the transition $\partial(q, a) = \emptyset$, will it end up in nowhere? Is it the same as saying the machine "halt"? So the input string is rejected and all the following symbols are discarded?
I interpret it like this: $\partial(q, a) = \emptyset$ means that the pair $(q, a)$ has a special transition that does nothing. Is this correct?

Background: I'm reading the online book here. In the book, they define/require the transition function of a DFA to be a total function $Q\times\Sigma \to Q$, so I never think about this "end up in nowhere" problem before.

In this section, I will provide an example to show what confuses me.
Given a NFA, $N=(Q,\Sigma, q_0, \partial, F)$, where $Q=\{q_0, q_1, q_2\}$, $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$, and $F=\{q_1\}$, and the transition function is defined as follow:
\begin{align}
\partial (q_0, a) &= \{q_1\} \\
\partial (q_0, b) &= \{q_2\} \\
\partial (q_1, a) &= \{q_0\} \\
\partial (q_1, b) &= \emptyset \\
\partial (q_2, a) &= \emptyset \\
\partial (q_2, b) &= \{q_0\} \\
\end{align}
and there is no $\varepsilon$-transition on all states in $Q$.
Given the starting state is $q_0$ and the input string is $ab$, then:

It could get rejected. The fact that $\partial(q_1, b)=\emptyset$ doesn't make me confident that $b$ would be consumed.
It could get accepted. Because in the end, the machine needs to read/consume the input symbol regardless of the image of $\partial(q_1, b)$. If $\partial(q_1, b)=\emptyset$ would indeed consume the symbol $b$ without making any move, it would stay in the state $q_1$. If $q_1$ is a final state, it will get accepted.


@SBF: Yes, according to the online book. I use $F_Q$ to make it more clear that it's a subset of $Q$, while the book simply use $F$.

iirc, NFA traces just stop once you reach $\partial(q,a) = \emptyset$. The input string though may have other trajectories available due to non-determinism. For it to be accepted you need to have at least one visit to $F_Q$ on at least one of the trajectories. I have mostly dealt with probabilistic automata, and non-deterministic ones always seemed to be somewhat weird exactly for the reasons like in your post. Some people have tried to repeat this in probabilistic setting by introducing cases where sum of probabilities is less than $1$. Fortunately, it does not work in general case there

@SBF "NFA traces just stop once you reach $\partial(q,a)=\emptyset$.": Am I correct to interpret it as: So $a$ will not even get consumed and the NFA would just stop this specific trace? (anyway, I didn't heard of probabilistic automata before. It sounds really cool)

Define consumed

@SBF By my "consumed", I try to divide the process into two phases "read symbol, then react". So while it is stuck in the react phase because of the $\emptyset$, the reading phase is finished. Apologies for this informalnism, but I tried to think of it like a real program, and we usually read the symbol first then decide what to react.

I was always thinking in terms of: what is the output of a given input sequence

If you have $\partial(q,a)=\emptyset$, that means that there is no transition out of $q$ that consumes symbol $a$.  Therefore, if you are imagining an execution that is at state $q$ and is trying to consume symbol $a$, execution cannot continue [1]. We might informally say that it "gets stuck".  (It is a little bit analogous to a process that core-dumps and crashes.)
Recall that a NFA accepts iff there is any execution run that consumes the entire input and ends in acceptance.  Therefore, an execution run that gets stuck partway through cannot possibly count as an accepting trace.
It might be tempting to think that the execution run gets "stuck at $q$" or "remains at $q$".  This isn't correct.  The execution run doesn't continue; instead, it disappears from existence.  A better intuition would be that the execution run dies / does not continue.  It's not in any state at all any longer.
All of these are analogies and intuition to help you understand the math.  The actual truth is given by the mathematical definition.  In any case of any doubt or ambiguity, refer to the mathematical definition for the precise answer.
[1] Unless there is an epsilon-transition that lets execution make progress to another state that can read symbol $a$.

One key difference between a NFA and a DFA is the form of the transition function $\partial$.
In the case of a DFA, $\partial \colon Q \times \Sigma \to Q$ is a single-valued function, which means that, given the current state $q \in Q$ and after reading any symbol $\sigma \in \Sigma$, the DFA will always enter a single, well-defined state $q' \in Q$ (hence the name "deterministic").
In the case of a NFA, instead, $\partial \colon Q \times (\Sigma \cup \{\varepsilon\}) \to \mathcal{P}(Q)$ can be seen as a multi-valued function, which means that, given the current state $q \in Q$ and after reading any symbol $σ \in \Sigma$ or no symbol (this is why the singleton $\{\varepsilon\}$ is added in the second component of the domain of $\partial$), the NFA may enter any state $q'$ from a single, well-defined subset $Q' \subseteq Q$ of the set of states (hence the name "nondeterministic").
Since the set $Q$ of states of an NFA is finite, every $Q' \subseteq Q$ is also finite, in particular it can be empty.
If for a given state $q \in Q$ and symbol $\sigma \in \Sigma \cup \{\varepsilon\}$ (possibly no symbol) the image $\partial (q, \sigma)$ is empty, it simply means that there is no transition to a new state from the state $q$ after reading the input symbol $\sigma$ (possibly after reading no symbol).
In this case, you cannot conclude immediately that the NFA must reject the input word. It just means that this particular nondeterministic transition path (that is, a sequence of transitions obtained by nondeterministically choosing a particular state from the image of $\partial$ as the starting point of the next transition) ends in the state $q$ when the input symbol to read (possibly none) is $\sigma$.
Thus, consider an NFA running for some input word following a particular transition path. Suppose that the NFA is in the state $q$ and is reading the symbol $\sigma \in \Sigma$ from the input word, and that $\partial(q, \sigma) = \emptyset = \partial(q,\varepsilon) $: then, that particular transition path is stuck (it cannot evolve more), and

if $q$ is an accepting state and $\sigma$ is the last symbol of the input word, then the NFA accepts the input word;

otherwise (that is, if $q$ is not an accepting state or $\sigma$ is not the last symbol of the input word), you have to look for some alternative transition paths that would circumvent this situation.


If no such an alternative transition path exists, then the NFA rejects the input word.
For a formal account, see here.

In the example of NFA at the end of the OP, there is only one possible transition path starting in the state $q_0$ with the input word $ab$: such a transition path ends in the state $q_1$ after reading the first symbol $a$ and then it gets stuck. We are in situation 2. described above, because $a$ is not the last symbol in the input word $ab$ (the last symbol, i.e. $b$, has to be read, but no transition from $(q_1, b)$ is possible), even though $q_1$ is an accepting state. Since there are no alternative transition paths, the word $ab$ is rejected by that NFA.
